# Cordova plugin Firebase did not receives push notifications if app in foreground for iOS application

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin for `push notifications`,

It works for Android, But in the iOS application does not receive the `push notification` when the app in the background state.

in iOS `onNotificationOpen` not working.

```
  try {
     window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function (data) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
     console.log(data, 'data');
       if (data.tap === true)
         {
         console.log('tapped');
         self.ngZone.run(() => self.router.navigate(['/worklist'])).then();
         }
       else 
         {
         console.log('not tapped');
         cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
         title: data.title,
         text: data.body,
         foreground: true,
         icon: '',
         smallIcon: ''
         });
    }
  });

      } catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you must set the variable `IOS_HIDE_FOREGROUND_NOTIFICACION` to `false` during plugin installation.